# Open UIView with navigation history with correct tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, tabs

I have some specific question:

My application have 4 tabs with independent navigation controllers under each of it.

Let's say tabs are: "Recent", "Chat List", "Contact" and "Settings".  Sometimes I need to open the "ChatView" controller from different tabs and places, like "Contacts" or "Recent". "ChatView" is located under "Chat List" tab (root controller is "ChatListView") and usually is displayed after selecting some existing conversation (in navigation stack it's like ChatListView -> ChatView).

I want to find the best way, how to open the "ChatView" controller with switching to the "Chat List" tab and reseting navigation history, so when user see the "ChatView", the back button we'll turn him to the "ChatListView", but not to "Contact" or some other place where he stayed before. Modal view will not work in this case, because I need both tab bar and navigation bar displayed.

Thank you for your advices!

## Update

Also please note that I need to pass some data to the newly opened ChatView controller. Just switching selected tab bar also is not enough, because I need to open View under its root controller (ChatListView -> ChatView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implicitly change tab to show by using `selectedIndex` property.
Try this:

```
NSInteger indexOfChatsTab = 1;
UINavigationController *chatsNavigationController = tabController.viewControllers[indexOfChatsTab];
[chatsNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[chatsNavigationController pushViewController:selectedChatViewController animated:NO];
controller.selectedIndex = indexOfChatsTab;
```

**Update:**
`selectedChatViewController` from above example is view controller that initialized by necessary data for displaying new chat.
I mean that before pushing you need initialize it like this:

```
ChatViewController *selectedChatViewController = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWithChatData:chatData];
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not enough, please check my update

Comment: @XFactor actually code from my example is not simply switches between tabs it also provide example for push new controller for displaying new chat. I've updated my answer with more description.

Comment: Sorry, it's clear now, except one point:
controller.selectedIndex = indexOfChatsTab; 

You mean selectedViewController in tabBarController here, right?

Comment: @XFactor As I understood you have tab with list of chats (that has index = indexOfChatsTab) then you tap on one of items in the list and new view controller is pushed (selectedChatViewController).

Comment: @XFactor I mean that my code example implements behavior described in previous comment without user interaction (as you need).

Comment: No matter, generally it works how I wanted. Have some GUI bugs but hope to fix them soon. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use setSelectedIndex property of UITabbarController.